# lexicographic order vs numeric order

Tags: c

According to K&R, `strcmp` cab be used to compare two lines, lexicographically. (p.119)

They use another function, `numcmp`, to compare two lines numerically. However, aren't these two descriptions basically the same?

Isn't the Lexicographic order of ASCII characters the order in which they appear on the list, which is determined by their machine integer value? That would mean that `numcmp` and `strcmp` are basically identical.

Edit:

When they say the numeric value of a line, do they mean adding up the ASCII integer values of all of the characters in the line?

Edit:

I'm not sure why my question is getting thumbed down. Should I inherently know what the numeric value of a line means?

Comment: "11" should be larger because isn't the second "1" compared to `'\0'`?

Comment: "numeric value of a line" means that `123` has value of the number `123`

Comment: Do you mean "123" is numerically 123? If so, what if the string elements are not digits?

Comment: Then there would be no numeric value.

Answer (score 10):

5 is numerically less than 10, but "10" is lexicographically less than "5".